# Error from recvfrom

Tags: c

I try to make a function that sends a icmp packet to another computer and when the other computer sends something back, the function returns a 1, else a 0. But the recvfrom function returns an error: "errno: Resource temporarily unavailable". I work on an Mac OS X, so I don't include headers from the linux kernel. Can anyone help me, cause I'm stuck.

```
#include "info.h"


char *getip()
{
    char buffer[256];
    struct hostent *h;

    gethostname(buffer, 256);
    h = gethostbyname(buffer);

    return inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)h->h_addr);

}


int host_alive(char *dst_addr, char *src_addr)
{
    struct ip *ippacket;
    struct ip *ip_reply;
    struct icmp *icmppacket;
    struct sockaddr_in connection;
    struct timeval tv;
    char *packet;
    char *buffer;
    int optval;
    int addrlen;
    int size;
    int sock = 0;

    packet = malloc(sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct icmp));
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct icmp));

    check(getuid() == 0, "Root priviliges are needed. Try: sudo ./bin/main");

    ippacket = (struct ip *) packet;
    icmppacket = (struct icmp *) (packet + sizeof(struct ip));

    ippacket->ip_hl = 5;
    ippacket->ip_v = 4;
    ippacket->ip_tos = 0;
    ippacket->ip_len = sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct icmp);
    ippacket->ip_id = htons(random());
    ippacket->ip_ttl = 255;
    ippacket->ip_p = IPPROTO_ICMP;
    inet_aton(src_addr, &ippacket->ip_src);
    inet_aton(dst_addr, &ippacket->ip_dst);

    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    check((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP)) != -1,\
          "Failed to create socket");

    check(setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &optval, sizeof(int)) != -1,\
          "Failed to set the option to the socket.");
    check(setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char *)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval)) != -1,\
          "Failed to set the option to the socket.");

    icmppacket->icmp_type = ICMP_ECHO;
    icmppacket->icmp_code = 0;
    icmppacket->icmp_id = 0;
    icmppacket->icmp_seq = 0;
    icmppacket->icmp_cksum = in_cksum((unsigned short *)icmppacket, sizeof(struct icmp));

    ippacket->ip_sum = in_cksum((unsigned short *)ippacket, sizeof(struct ip));

    connection.sin_family = AF_INET;
    connection.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(dst_addr);

    sendto(sock, packet, ippacket->ip_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&connection,\
          sizeof(struct sockaddr));

    addrlen = sizeof(connection);
    check((size = recvfrom(sock, buffer, sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct icmp), 0,\
      (struct sockaddr *)&connection, (socklen_t *)&addrlen)) != -1,\
      "Failed to receive a message.");

    printf("Received %d byte reply from %s:\n", size , dst_addr);
    ip_reply = (struct ip*) buffer;
    printf("ID: %d\n", ntohs(ip_reply->ip_id));
    printf("TTL: %d\n", ip_reply->ip_ttl);

    close(sock);

    free(packet);
    free(buffer);

    return 1;

  error:
    if (sock)
        close(sock);
    free(packet);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}


unsigned short in_cksum(unsigned short *addr, int len)
{
    int sum = 0;
    u_short answer = 0;
    u_short *w = addr;
    int nleft = len;

    while (nleft > 1) {
        sum += *w++;
        nleft -= 2;
    }

    if (nleft == 1) {
        *(u_char *) (&answer) = *(u_char *) w;
        sum += answer;
    }
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    answer = ~sum;
    return (answer);
}
```

Comment: Which errno code are you getting? There's a list of possible errors at the end of `man recvfrom`.

Comment: Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: I mean the number, the `Exxxx` code. That's the English message and it's not one of the expected results from calling that function. Is it possibly `EAGAIN`?

Comment: I get only this: [ERROR] (src/info.c:77: errno: Resource temporarily unavailable) Failed to receive a message.

Comment: what is the contents of `info.h`?

Comment: You may need the 'keep alive' option on the socket, set with the `setsockopt()` function.  It could be the server has not yet responded or the server hung-up,  Suggest using the function: `perror()` to get the reason the system thinks the function failed.   If the returned status is `EAGAIN` then loop, calling the `recvfrom()` function until either an error (other than EAGAIN) or the returned value from the function is 0 (the server hung up) or some actual data is received.

Comment: the returned value from `recvfrom()` can be <0, =0, or >0.  From the other uses of the `check()` function, I suspect it does not do that 3 way checking properly

Comment: the posted code is failing to check the results of the calls to `malloc()`, `sendto()`,  This means when any of those function calls fails, the code will blissfully continue, even though it should be reporting the error, cleaning up, and calling `exit()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for `recvfrom` this is expected if you're using a non-blocking call:

> If no messages are available at the socket, the receive call waits for a message to arrive, unless the socket is nonblocking (see `fcntl(2)`) in which case the value -1 is returned and the external vari-
>      able errno set to `EAGAIN`.  The receive calls normally return any data available, up to the requested amount, rather than waiting for receipt of the full amount requested; this behavior is affected by the
>      socket-level options `SO_RCVLOWAT` and `SO_RCVTIMEO` described in `getsockopt(2)`.

You can look up `errno` values in `/usr/include/sys/errno.h` if you're curious as to what values map to what errors.

If you want this function to block you may need to set the `MSG_WAITALL` flag which "requests that the operation block until the full request is satisfied".

Normally in low-level UNIX socket code you'd do a `select` on that socket to wait for a read signal, then call `recvfrom` to receive the data if and only if that signal triggered. You can also do a non-blocking receive and on an `EAGAIN` just wait a short period of time before trying again, though that is less efficient.

Comment: Thank you, but it the function doesn't work either with an IP address, which is responding when you ping it.

Comment: It's worth adding a `select` call here for the timeout feature alone, though.

Comment: You mean, use select to catch a signal, and if it catches the signal, the data can be returned by recvfrom. What is the name of that signal?

Comment: It's not a signal so much as a "ready to read" indicator. I've found [this book](http://www.unpbook.com) to be really helpful, but you might know of another reference that covers this topic. "Signal" in UNIX programming means something like `SIGKILL` or `SIGINT`, process-level signals.